# $http.delete() via AngularJS to Laravel backend API results in 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, http-status-code-405, codekit

I'm creating an Recipe application with an AngularJS frontend, and a Laravel backend (setup as an API). When I'm looking at a detailed view of an recipe, I want the user to have the possibility to delete the recipe. Therefore I've added this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="recipeData.id" ng-click="deleteRecipe(recipeData.id)">
  Delete
</button>
```

..which calls for this function:

```
$scope.deleteRecipe = function(id) {
    Recipes.destroy(id)
      .success(function() {
        $location.path('/');
      })
  }
```

..that uses this service/factory:

```
destroy : function(id) {
      return $http.delete('/api/recipes/' + id);
    }
```

..which should be routed according to these rules Laravel routing rules:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
  Route::resource('recipes', 'RecipeController');
  Route::resource('ingredients', 'IngredientController');
  Route::resource('nutrients', 'NutrientController');
  Route::resource('IngredientsByRecipe', 'IngredientsByRecipeController');
});
```

..and in our RecipeController we find this function which should take care of the finishing job:

```
  public function destroy($id)
  {
    Recipe::destroy($id);
    return Response::json(array('success' => true));
  }
```

..but somehow I can't get this to work because I get this error message in my browsers console:

```
DELETE http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/4 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

..when I run this command below however, via the terminal, I recieve no errors and the specific recipe is deleted without problems.

```
curl -v -X DELETE http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/4
```

This problem only occurs while I'm running CodeKits browser-auto-refresh-tool. Can't figure out why. Posting the two headers below to see if you notice anything strange. With CodeKit:

```
DELETE /api/recipes/8 HTTP/1.1
Host: marcuss-macbook-air.local:5757
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://marcuss-macbook-air.local:5757
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://marcuss-macbook-air.local:5757/edit/8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
Cookie: __ngDebug=true; ckrp_ypos=0_0; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjFiVWRNSkZhK3hualwvS1FCd29SMk1vaVhJN0Q4Q1RJS1k2TDFnUHBQTWFzPSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOUtRUUFRbUJlaDcyZHJIZE1oQnphUm1wTlZiYmZoQ1VKZXdTWngwM1hLV2s3VjlrSzZ1b3E2Q0dsK1wvRk1mZlNHaG1wcWxBcjc5V2QzOVpSOXpHRElRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJkNjliMDZjMThjYmVjZDZhZjU2N2ZmMzkwYTUzMjBmYmVlZDc4ZWVlZmFlOWY1YzE5NWYwZDIxNDkwNGU5YmRiIn0%3D
```

Without CodeKit:

```
DELETE /api/recipes/7 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8000/edit/7
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
Cookie: __ngDebug=true; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ik5iVWpESEYyRk45Yys5REV1OUdOcHlyTXd6YkNsSFlETTFlUkVhNjdseE09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJVRlFka1hERTBmMGJQb3dBQ2YyQmIzZnNGb2hab1VldmFhUUhHeE00czdqUytmVUdXQXRDbXJPc0lTRUpGZDY2K0V3alNHejRIY0JsdkNxQ1ExdlJoZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNzQ2YzIyODRkZjQ0ZTdjODI0YzYxMTVjMzc0ZTJhM2UzZmQyM2Y4OGIwYmJkMzU2ZWNiNzU1NzgzYzBkZDY0ZSJ9
```

What is the cause for my DELETE-requests to get 405'ed via Angular (using CodeKit) but not via my curl-request in the terminal or normal use of Angular?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the laravel route defined?

Comment: And post the HTTP headers of the request from your network tab in the developer tools please.

Comment: Updated my post with routes. Is this the HTTP headers of the requst you're asking for: DELETE /api/recipes/4 HTTP/1.1
, Method:DELETE
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed?

Comment: No, like I said, go to developer tools, send the request through your web application, click the request in the network tab, post the headers.

Comment: Post the Request Headers & Response Headers.

Comment: Also since you're using route resources in your API, is there any reason you chose not to use Angular's `$resource`?

Comment: You know what? The 405 error only occurs when I'm using the application through CodeKits "browser-refreshing-tool". When I accessed the app via http//localhost:8000 everything worked! Can't figure out why though.

Comment: Don't know what that is.

Comment: Not familiar with $resource in Angular, but maybe I should give it a thought. Looked like a simpler way instead of writing custom services?

Comment: It'll match with your Laravel route resource if it's all normal https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Okay! Check my new edit to the post if you can help me out with this CodeKit problem :/

Comment: I don't know what Codekit is or anything about it so if it's a problem because of that I'd suggest tagging it in your question or finding the IRC channel or equivalent for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeKit does not support the DELETE method. So this is the reason why it works with other clients.

There is an open issue for this on GitHub: [#398](https://github.com/bdkjones/CodeKit/issues/398)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to work around this problem?

Comment: This would work but probably is not a good idea..  Change the method to GET and send a GET request instead.